# Restoring MacBook Pro 9.1 (2012) Firmware to versions as shipped with Lion

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, firmware, downgrade

I was hoping to get a second life out a set of 2012 MacBook Pros (MacBook Pro 9.1, A1286, MD104) using Linux or booting into Windows for retro activities. However, later versions of the firmware (installed during Mojave and later) remove older, more-compatible hardware modes. This prevents things like Ethernet from working correctly in non-MacOS OSes.

I'm hoping to find a way to downgrade the Firmware from 233.0.0.0 -> 00DA B00 or to the originally shipped firmware.

Anybody have a procedure to restore the original firmware?

In the absence of that, anybody have a copy of the original firmware? I'm not opposed to hexediting images and reprogramming the firmware (on or off the board).

I was hoping to find a set of older firmware on my various MBP9,1s but they are all the newer firmware.

Comment: According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468) your model Mac is Windows 10 compatible. It is unlikely that Apple introduced a firmware upgrade that would remove this compatibility. However,  most likely Windows 10 on your model Mac would need to be installed to BIOS boot.

Comment: As for the firmware, I believe the only way to go backwards is to replace the logic board. However, if you wish to try, then [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311947/how-to-update-latest-macbook-pro-efi-firmware-manually/311990#311990) may be useful.

Comment: If you choose to install a BIOS booting Windows or Linux, you probable could do so by booting the installer from a USB port. However, you may find burning a DVD would be easier.

Comment: Can you reinstall Lion?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Apple installs firmware updates to stop non-Apple OS's from accessing Ethernet?  "Hardware modes"?